# Примеение Binary File Descriptor library

Tags: linux, arm, elf

Добрый день.

Моя программа main.elf использует динамическую библиотеку (libdso.so),
которая находиться в том же каталоге.

Библиотека использует только себя.

Подскажите , а возможно отредактировать main.elf файл так то бы 
libdso.so было скомпоновано внутри исполняемого файла?

Возможно ли это сделать с применением библиотеки bfd?
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/bfd-2.9.1/html_mono/bfd.html

Comment: Есть подозрение что статическая линковка вас спасет.

Comment: libdso.so нет исходников. И вопрос больше исследовательский. Возможно ли такое вообще?

Comment: А, сорцов нет...

Comment: libdso.so нет исходников.